# Windows 10 service host consuming more internet

Tags: internet

I have a limited internet usage plan. I can't afford to lose much data.

So I have 
    1. **Metered** the internet connection 
    2. Disabled **BITS service**
    3. Disabled **Windows Update**

But still it is consuming my internet bandwidth.

Here is the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Task manager and the services]

Can anyone please tell me the solution ?

Comment: Obviously you need a better monitoring tool as task manager does not show what service is using the bandwith. Please get Process Explorer from Technet, enable the "IO" columns and then check the winnt.exe-> services.exe subprocesses. You can see the network IO when you doubleclick one process and check the "IO-> other" column

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 telemetry continually sends information about your PC to Microsoft, and Windows push messaging (advertising, Bing news etc.) and Cortana Innternet searches continually uses bandwidth to send data to you.

1. Eliminate live tiles, such as weather, news or stock tickers. Right click on each app to turn it off, or use [this setting hack](https://betanews.com/2016/06/03/disable-windows-10-live-tiles/) to shut them all.
2. Turn off Cortana searching on the web.
3. Eliminate telemetry with a privacy tool such as [ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) or [W10Privacy](https://www.winprivacy.de/english-home/) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/w10privacy/). Use caution, since some settings can disable useful functions.

Do *not* permanently disable BITS and Update service because updates often plug security holes in Windows. If need be, go to a library or other free WiFi provider to get updates. Once the OS is up-to-date, those services should have minimal impact on data usage. Furthermore, you can set usage limits in the Window Update Advanced Options.

[image: Window Update usage options]

If you have two or more PC's with similar versions of Windows, you might want to have one download updates for both in the Delivery Optimization CPL.

[image: Update Delivery Optimization]